# Log in to Gmail API

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm trying to authenticate my web app with the Gmail API using my Client ID and Client Secret. The authentication in the "quick start" example, located [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-cs), seems oddly complicated. Step 4, however, states:

> Note: The authorization flow in this example is greatly simplified for demonstration purposes and should not be used in web applications. For more information, see [Authorizing your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth).

but the link provided there is broken. Has anyone successfully created a simple authentication for the Gmail API in C#?

I'm mostly asking this question so that it can serve as a resource for others who aren't able to find the answer to this.

Comment: I searched the link itself, and Google came out with this URL: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth hope it helps.

Comment: Why do they limit some of their examples to Python? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broken link should be:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

For the C# Auth try something like:

```
// Create OAuth Credential.
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    },
    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None).Result;

// Create the service.
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Draft Sender",
});

ListDraftsResponse draftsResponse = service.Users.Drafts.List("me").Execute();
```